# Net Core - Cookie SameSite

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, samesite

I found the problem in my project. The problem is that the cookie is not saved when the user is logged in via the iframe. Cookies are saved when you log in to the site normally, that is, directly through the domain. There are 2 different problems for me right now:

1. When logging into the site directly ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), the relevant cookie is saved. But this cookie is saved as Lax. I want it to be saved as none.
2. If there is no direct login to the site before, if you want to log in from within the iframe, the cookie is not saved. I want to create cookies on logins made via iframe.

I did not perform anything on the cookie. I guess SignAsync() creates the relevant cookies automatically. I am also attaching my codes inside the Account Controller.

```
  public IActionResult Login(string returnurl)
    {
        return View(new LoginViewModel {ReturnUrl=returnurl, IsPersistent=true });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.IsPersistent, true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl ?? "/");
        }

        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid User Login");
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

I also tried the solutions in the links below but it didn't work for me. Maybe I have applied these solutions incorrectly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/security/samesite/rp31?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0

And here is a photo:

[Cookie View with Cookie Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHj5A.png)

Comment: This seems related to the security in broswer like : Chrome.  iframes no logner support carrying cookies to access third-party sites. The link you provided is what we developer can do, set samesite=none and enable secure(https).

Comment: And if the link not useful to you, we can't let users use the lower version browser, right ? So my suggestion is we can use token to replace it.

Comment: Hi Jason, I know this is the solution that works for me. But I don't know how to set this cookie created to SameSite=none. I tried the solution in the links I added. But it didn't work for me. The cookie is still added as 'Lax'. Can you help me how to do this?

Comment: Hi Salih, can we get more information about the error? Base on the second document, it should be done. Or maybe that's because the browser is older version? You can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#sob), it may help you.

Comment: Hi Yang, the problem for me: Add a sugar at the samesite that lax instead of none. Here's how I don't know.